# OpenCV grayscale image has shape (H,W) but I need (H,W,1) for Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, opencv

I use this command to convert an open cv image from RGB to grayscale:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Grayscale image
```

Printing the shape before this command returns the following:

```
(64, 128, 3)
```

And after the grayscale function:

```
(64, 128)
```

However it should be like this:

```
(64, 128, 1)
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how I can get my image to a proper format? Because if I pass this image on to Tensorflow it gives me an error due to wrong input shape. Tensorflow expects an image with the following format (width, height, channels). Channels is either 3 for rgb or 1 for grayscale. In my case however I don't have any channels after the conversion to grayscale. And I don't know why

Comment: gray scale image is one channel image and it's not necessary to generate (64,128,1) to showing number of channels.

Comment: That is uncorrect unfortunately. Tensorflow always needs an input shape of (width, height, channels) or it will crash.

Comment: So add a channel to output of your image: tf.expand_dims(image, -1).shape.as_list()

Comment: "does not work properly"... that's a rather useless title. collapsing 1-sized dimensions is a valid design decision. it **does** work properly. you just need to know a little numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input images are 3 channels but gray scales have one channel.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("HHH.jpg")
print(f"img.shape={img.shape}")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Grayscale image
print(f"gray.shape={gray.shape}")
```

output:

```
img.shape=(960, 1280, 3)
gray.shape=(960, 1280)
```

If you need to feed images in (H, W, 1) dimension to TensorFlow, so change your dimension by **expanding dimension** in TF:
This code adds a one channel to last dimension of data:

```
 tf.expand_dims(image, -1).shape.as_list()
```

Comment: For some reason the tf command does not work for me. However the idea behind it makes sense and is correct. I added a dimension with numpy instead and now it works.
img = img[:, :, np.newaxis]